# Is FirebaseRecyclerAdapter not applicable in com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

Import `com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` is showing error.
Is FirebaseRecyclerAdapter not applicable in `com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0`?

Please help me out.

Comment: it is supported have a look at https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android

Comment: which FirebaseUI version are u including in the grade file ? for 10.2.0 you should import 1.2.0 version of Firebase UI

Comment: thank u guys it's worked for me

Answer (score 1):

In your module build.gradle dependencies, replace:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
```

with

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
```

Comment: isn't it `com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:X.X.X` that should be replaced? because I think Firebase UI database (even version 1.2.0) still need `com.google.firebase:firebase-database:X.X.X`.

Comment: @koceeng: The Firebase UI libraries have [transitive dependencies](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#compatibility-with-firebase--google-play-services-libraries) on the SDK libraries.  The SDK libraries do not need to be listed in the module dependencies.

Comment: so we don't need to add `com.google.firebase:firebase-database:X.X.X` in our app-level gradle? And thanks for this new info

Comment: @koceeng: Yes, if your app-level gradle has a dependency for `firebase-ui-database`, you do not need to also include `firebase-database`, although it does no harm.  Not including it simplifies the dependencies list and reduces the risk of version mismatches.